# Format ListViewItems in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, richtextbox

How can add items from a `ListView` to a `RichTextBox` programmatically?

For example in this image shown below, I want the `ListViewItem` instances from specified columns to be shown in a `RichTextBox` and I want them to be formatted as a table. How can I do that?

In the image below, I typed the values into the `RichTextBox`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
     {
        for (int j = 0; j < listView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += listView1.Items[i].SubItems[j].Text.ToString()+"\t";
        }
        richTextBox1.Text += "\n";

      }
```

**Updated**

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
     richTextBox1.Text += listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text.ToString();
     richTextBox1.Text += "\t"+listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text.ToString();
     richTextBox1.Text += "\n";                                    
}
```

Comment: I know this is not a way you like...... You can put if(j==1) continue; before  richTextBox1.Text += listView1.Items[i].SubItems[j].Text.ToString()+"\t"; I am trying for alternate way I will tell you soon.....